# How to supervise the number of clusters (R)?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a directed graph (vertices =20, edges<100). The function edge.betweenness.community() was used, and 5 clusters were found. The sizes of clusters are different: 14, 3, 1, 1, 1.
[image: picture with example of 5 cluster] 
Script is below.

```
ga.data<- read.csv('q2_4.csv', header=TRUE) 
g <- graph.data.frame(ga.data, directed=TRUE)
gnc <- edge.betweenness.community(g, directed=TRUE)

windows()
plot(gnc, g, vertex.frame.color="black", edge.color="black",
edge.arrow.size=0.5, edge.width=.1, vertex.label.font=NA)

# print the lables of vertices 

for (i in 1: length(gnc)) {
print(V(g2)[clusters(g2)$membership == i])
}
```

The output is:

```
#    + 14/20 vertices, named:
#     [1] A19 A15 A09 A16 A20 A01 A06 A13 A10 A18 A08 A14 A02 A03
#    + 1/20 vertex, named:
#    [1] A17
#    + 1/20 vertex, named:
#    [1] A11
#    + 3/20 vertices, named:
#    [1] A12 A04 A07
#    + 1/20 vertex, named:
#    [1] A05
```

I would like to supervise the number of clusters and divide all vertices into 4 clusters. I added the line in the script:

```
print(gnh<- cutat(gnc, no = 4)) # set number of clusters = 4
#[1] 1 1 3 4 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

A certain number of communities in the last line. 
How to assign names to the result?

Comment: Use `cutat` on the result to get 4 clusters. It is unlikely that they'll have 5 vertices each, though.

Comment: @GaborCsardi, thank you for comment. I have updated my question and tried to apply your suggestion.